# Value of $4\sin^2(\alpha)$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

If the point on $y=x\tan(\alpha)-\frac{ax^2}{2u^2\cos^2(\alpha)}$ ,$\alpha>0$ where the tangent is parallel to $y=x$ has an ordinate $\frac{u^2}{4a}$ then value of $4\sin^2(\alpha)$ is?. If we substitute $y$ in the given equation we get a quadratic in $x$ whose roots are $-\tan(\alpha)\pm\sqrt{\tan^2(\alpha)-1}$  . Also $\frac{dy}{dx}=1$ but after doing this I don't get an equation in $\alpha$ as there is an $u$ making things difficult . I don't know how to proceed. Note that answer is an integer from $[0-9]$. Any hints ?

Comment: Hint: If the tangent is parallel to $y=x$, then the derivative of the function has slope $1$ at that point. Solve for the derivative being $1$, substitute into the function definition, and figure out what has to happen for the function value there to be $\frac{u^2}{4\alpha}$.

Answer (score 1):

You must also assume $u \ne 0$ and $\cos(\alpha)\ne 0$. The slope of the tangent at any point is given by the derivative with respect to $x$, which will be a linear function and therefore will equal 1 at exactly one value of $x$.

Compute the derivative with respect to $x$ and set that equal to 1. Solve for $x$ (expressed as a function of the parameters $u$ and $\alpha$). If I did this right, you should get $x = \dfrac{\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)}{\alpha} u$.

Then plug this back into the equation to compute the value of $y$ at this $x$ (that is the "ordinate" of the point where the tangent has slope 1). Set that equal to $\dfrac{u^2}{4\alpha}$; you will see that a lot of simplifications take place, in particular $u$ is eliminated from the equation. This will lead you to the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P \equiv  \left(x,\frac{u^2}{4a}\right) $

Then by $$y=x\tan(\alpha)-\frac{ax^2}{2u^2\cos^2(\alpha)}$$

we get $$\frac{u^2}{4a}=x\tan(\alpha)-\frac{ax^2}{2u^2\cos^2(\alpha)}$$

$$\frac{u^2}{4}=ax\tan(\alpha)-\frac{(ax)^2}{2u^2\cos^2(\alpha)}\rightarrow (1)$$

And $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\tan(\alpha)-\frac{ax}{u^2\cos^2(\alpha)}$$

$$1=\tan(\alpha)-\frac{ax}{u^2\cos^2(\alpha)}$$

$$(\tan\alpha-1)(u^2\cos^2\alpha)=ax \rightarrow (2)$$

Thus by $(1)$ & $(2)$ ,

$$\frac{u^2}{4}=(\tan\alpha-1)(u^2\cos^2\alpha)\tan\alpha-\frac{(\tan\alpha-1)^2(u^2\cos^2\alpha)^2}{2u^2\cos^2\alpha}$$

$$\frac{u^2}{4}=(\tan\alpha-1)(u^2\cos^2\alpha)\tan(\alpha)-\frac{(\tan\alpha-1)^2(u^2\cos^2\alpha)}{2}$$

$$\frac{\sec^2 \alpha}{4}=(\tan\alpha-1)\tan\alpha-\frac{(\tan\alpha-1)^2}{2}$$

$$\frac{\sec^2 \alpha}{4}=\tan^2\alpha-\tan\alpha-\frac{\tan^2\alpha}{2}+\tan\alpha -\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\frac{\sec^2 \alpha}{4}=\frac{\tan^2\alpha}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\sec^2 \alpha=2\tan^2\alpha-2$$

$$1+\tan^2 \alpha=2\tan^2\alpha-2$$

$$\tan^2\alpha =3$$

Thus $$4\sin ^2 \alpha =3$$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is the same as the equation of the trajectory of a projectile, with $a$ instead of $g$.

Treating it as a mechanics problem, we can parametrize the curve with
$$x=ut\cos\alpha$$ $$y=ut\sin\alpha-\frac 12 at^2$$

So we have$$\dot{x}=u\cos\alpha$$ 
$$\dot{y}=u\sin\alpha-at$$

When $\frac{dy}{dx}=1$ we can set $\dot{x}=\dot{y}\implies t=\frac ua(\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha)$

We can substitute the value of $t$ in the $y$ equation.

We then have $$\frac{u^2}{4a}=\frac{u^2}{a}(\sin^2\alpha-\sin\alpha\cos\alpha)-\frac{u^2}{a}(1-2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha)$$

This reduces to $$\sin^2\alpha=\frac 34$$